# What's the workflow for creating an iOS app

Tags: ios, delphi, workflow, delphi-xe2

What's the workflow for creating an iOS app using Delphi-XE2.

*This is really a reference question and I'll answer it as soon as SO lets me, but I thought it would be nice to have the answer here*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**iOS Applications**
***FireMonkey iOS applications are written in Delphi:***

```
File > New > Other > Delphi Projects > FireMonkey iOS HD Application 
File > New > Other > Delphi Projects > FireMonkey iOS 3D Application
```

*Projects for iOS do not have a Target Platforms node in the Project Manager; they only target iOS*

**iOS Forms**
Additional Delphi forms are added the same way as with Windows and Mac OS X. Because the target platform is iOS, and the production executable is built with the Free Pascal compiler, the uses declaration for form units is different:

```
 uses
   SysUtils, Types, Classes, Variants, FMX_Types, FMX_Controls, FMX_Forms,
   FMX_Dialogs, FMX_ExtCtrls, FMX_Ani;
```

**iOS Workflow**
FireMonkey iOS development has to be done using **both** Windows and a Mac.
Before starting your first iOS project, you must perform one-time setup on both ends. Then for each project, development occurs in the following sequence:

- Create project in RAD Studio on Windows.
- Save project files to a shared directory or media accessible to both Windows and Mac.
- Use the Form Designer and code editor in RAD Studio.
- Run or debug the project in RAD Studio as a Win32 application for prototyping.
- At least once after creating the project, and whenever new files are added to the project, run dpr2xcode on Windows to create or update a corresponding Xcode project.
- In Xcode on the Mac, open the .xcodeproj file in the generated xcode subdirectory of the shared project.
- Run or debug the project in Xcode with the iOS Simulator and then on a device for production testing.
- Iteratively develop the application using the Form Designer or code editor in RAD Studio, or the code editor in Xcode, making sure to save files as you work so that changes can be seen everywhere.

**Compiler and Runtime Differences**
Xcode builds the application with the Free Pascal compiler to run on the Free Pascal runtime library. Some features of the Delphi compiler and RTL are not supported by Free Pascal.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is in the help file, and also you should check out the "FireMonkey Platform Prerequisites" topic to get started too.